# Get CPU idle percentage for each core from dstat for variable amount of cores

Tags: awk, grep, cpu-usage

I have over 100 servers, all using different CPUs which may have from 2 to 16 cores.

I can get the idle CPU for each core via the following command (dstat is installed on all servers):

```
dstat -c -C 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7  --noheaders --nocolor --noupdate 3 1
```

I know number of cores at the time of execution, so number of cores that goes into -C will be different. The output is as follows:

```
-------cpu0-usage------ -------cpu1-usage------ -------cpu2-usage------ -------cpu3-usage------ -------cpu4-usage------ -------cpu5-usage------ -------cpu6-usage------ -------cpu7-usage------
usr sys idl wai hiq siq:usr sys idl wai hiq siq:usr sys idl wai hiq siq:usr sys idl wai hiq siq:usr sys idl wai hiq siq:usr sys idl wai hiq siq:usr sys idl wai hiq siq:usr sys idl wai hiq siq
  5   3  90   0   0   2:  4   3  91   0   0   2:  4   3  91   0   0   2:  6   4  88   0   0   2:  2   1  96   0   0   1:  2   1  96   0   0   1:  2   1  96   0   0   1:  7   5  75   0   0  13
  3   1  95   0   0   1:  2   1  96   0   0   0:  5   2  93   0   0   1:  2   1  96   0   0   1:  1   0  99   0   0   0:  1   1  97   0   0   1:  1   0  98   0   0   0: 23  16  16   0   0  45
```

I need to "extract" the `idl` value for each core, from the last row, and spit it out in a comma separated format. So from the data-set above, I want to have the following output:

95,96,93,96,99,97,98,16

My grep/awk-foo is quite poor, can someone assist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk '{out=""; for (i=3;i<=NF;i+=6) out = out (i>3?",":"") $i} END{print out}' file
95,96,93,96,99,97,98,16
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `tail -n1` to get the last line of the output.  Sounds like you need every 6th column starting at the 3rd column?  A for loop in awk can do that.  And then use `tr` to change newlines into commas as you want:

```
yourcommand | tail -n1 | awk '{for (i=3; i<=NF; i+=6) print $i }' | tr '\n' ','
```

Comment: Thanks, almost works. How do I start it at the 3rd column?

Comment: Should've been `i=3` in the awk command. Fixed in the answer.

Comment: That will add a trailing comma at the end of the line and produce output with no terminating newline so the result is not a POSIX text "file" and so YMMV wrt what any subsequent command would be able to do with it.